# Hazelcast external sorting.Sort records in a big csv

Tags: csv, sorting, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I have a use case where I need to sort a huge csv file say 10 million records, and write result to another file. Does hazelcast-jet / hazelcast provide any such external sort capability where I have limited RAM.

Comment: You could do it using custom processors, but that's an advanced usage. By using the built-in features it's not possible as of today (Jet 4.2).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on introducing this feature as part of my GSoC project for Hazelcast Jet.
I used RocksDB state backend feature I developed earlier to do the sorting, so you can sort datasets larger than memory.
It's currently intended for batch use cases and to use it in the pipeline you call `BatchStage.sort(keyFn)` where `keyFn` extracts the key to sort on.
you can see the code on this [PR](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/pull/2257)

Answer (score 0):

10 milion records is nothing. I doubt it is hazelcast you really need here. Use the sort command coming with unix:

```
 sort --field-separator=',' --key=2 source.csv > target.csv
```

You can wrap this command with Java code like this:

```
Process sortProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

If you insist on using Hazelcast, you need to keep your memory footprint low. Keep everything else except the columns you are sorting as byte array.